# Redefine v to \upsilon in maths without affecting \url from hyperref

Tags: math-mode, fonts, pdftex, hyperref, eulervm

I want to use Euler as my math font, but I make extensive use of both v and \nu in my maths.
To my eyes \upsilon is very like the rounded "v" defined by many maths fonts, and I have attempted to redefine v to use the character slot from \upsilon. The MWE below works perfectly on the maths, but breaks in urls which are presumably typeset in tt but inside a maths enviroment.

Is there any way to achieve this substitution but protect the behaviour of hyperref?
I only want to affect the output of "v" when it will be typeset in euler, otherwise leave it alone.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[small, T1]{eulervm}
\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"1D}

\begin{document}

Maths with correct ``v'', that doesn't look like $\nu$.

\begin{equation}
\nu(v) = \frac{1 + \nu}{v}
\end{equation}

But the problem arises in urls, e.g. \url{https://veryrealurl.org}

\end{document}
```

Screenshot:
[image: Problem with URL when substituting v for upsilon]

Comment: Now your v looks like an upsilon to me ... This becomes very much apparent when you place it next to other italics letters (e.g., $u$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen To me it's no more out of place than the conventional euler $v$ which doesn't follow the rounded v shape of most maths fonts (e.g. cm). So long as a clear distinction can be made, I don't personally feel it matters; I will define the symbol (e.g. as velocity) where it is used. Complete sample of euler in Fig. 3 http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this could work (but imho it would be better not to map v to another char):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[small, T1]{eulervm}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\REALV}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`v}
\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"1D}
\makeatletter
\appto\UrlSpecials{\do\v{\REALV}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Maths with correct ``v'', that doesn't look like $\nu$.

\begin{equation}
\nu(v) = \frac{1 + \nu}{v}
\end{equation}

But the problem arises in urls, e.g. \url{https://veryrealurl.org}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This appears to work nicely in my large document too! I will see how much effort it is to replace all necessary vs with a \varv macro, but it's nice to have a backup plan!

Comment: How would you redefine "math v" to be "italics v"? IMHO, that looks much better than upsilon.